# Hot to set up permissions for GraphQL with graphene and SQLalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, graphql, graphene-python

I have Clients, Users, Projects and Trips on my graphene schema:

```
class Clients(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ClientModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

class Users(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

class Projects(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

class Trips(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = TripModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )
```

What I want to do is to setup permissions so someone pass an access token that matches one specific Client, and shows only the users, projects and trips of that specific Client.

How to do this? Is there a method on graphene to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I did it with `flask_httpauth`:

```
from flask_httpauth import HTTPTokenAuth
@auth.verify_token
def verify_token(token):
    for client in ClientModel.query.all():
        if client.access_token == token:
            g.current_user = client
            return True
    return False
```

Then I just put the `login_required` decorator on every `resolve_` function on my Query class, like this:

```
@auth.login_required
    def resolve_clients(self, info):
        current_client = g.current_user
        for client in ClientModel.query.all():
            if client.id == current_client.id:
                return client
        return None
```